# Noun phrase and is

Tags: parsing, noun-phrases

Given the following sentence

> Mark is not suited to countries where cheese is available.

would it be correct to say that there are  two separate noun phrases here?

[Mark is not suited] and [countries where cheese is available]

I am bit confused about the verb 'is',  specifically under what conditions it forms part of a noun phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Mark is not suited" is not a noun phrase in the example sentence:

> Mark is not suited to countries where cheese is available.

Indeed "is not suited" acts as the main verb of this sentence, so the subject is simply "Mark".

A good test for a noun phrase is "Can it be replaced by a single pronoun, and leave a grammatically valid sentence?" Replacing "Mark is not suited" in the example would leave:

> He to countries where cheese is available.

That is not a valid sentence, for one thing it does not contain a verb. Replacing jsut "Mark" leaves:

> He is not suited to countries where cheese is available.

That is a valid sentence.

Now at the other end "countries where cheese is available" **is** a noun phrase. "where cheese is available" is a restrictive relative clause indicating which countries are meant. such clauses can form part of a noun phrase. Again the replacement test leaves:

> Mark is not suited to them.

which is a valid sentence.

Comment: does this test always hold ? For example, "Joe is nice and gives  us useful advice such as "you only live once"'.   In this case,  'Joe is nice' cannot be replace by a pronoun (right?) neither  does 'useful advice such as "you only live once"''

Comment: "Joe is nice" is not a noun phrase here. I can't think of a case where "X is Y" would be. "useful advice..." is, and can be replaced. For example:  "Joe is nice and gives us it". "it" can replace the entire noun phrase.  I am not sure that the replacement rule handles every case, but I haven't found a case where it does not work to show what is or is not a noun phrase.

Comment: "**The counselor at the school** is **the woman who gave me that advice**."--->"She is she.", "She is her.", "That is her."?

Comment: @Lorel You can have "NP1 is NP2" as a sentence, yes. But I don't see that  "X is Y" can itself be a NP. Perhaps i am overlooking something. In your example there seem to be two NPs, joined by "is".

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

In the example sentence

> - *Mark is not suited to countries where cheese is available.*

there are **three** noun phrases:

1. *Mark* is the subject of the main clause; *is not suited* is the verb
2. *countries* is the object of the preposition *to*
3. *cheese* is the subject of the subordinate clause *where cheese is available*

The important thing is not the number of noun phrases but the fact that there are two clauses, each with a subject, and one subordinate to the other. The bracketing looks like this:

- *[ [Mark] is not suited [to [countries] ]

    [where [cheese] is available] ].*

As can be seen, the only constituents in the sentence are the main clause with its prepositional phrase and the relative clause modifying the object of the preposition. Each clause has a subject and the preposition has an object; none of the other constituents are noun phrases, since the prepositional phrase modifies a verb and the relative clause modifies a noun.